# CSS dosen't work with my PHP code (echo/no echo)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to convert an html theme to work with Wordpress and I got stuck on a rather simple code and I don't understand why.

Why does this code:

```
<div class="project-category text-faded">
    test
</div>
```

not work the same as this (CSS doesn't work)?

```
<div class="project-category text-faded">
     <?php the_category(); ?>
</div>

<a href="-----/category/test/" rel="category tag">Test</a> as output of <?php the_category(); ?>
```

Comment: you don't know what you are trying..... you are writing a php function of wordpress cms and running it.

Comment: I know what i am doing it's running on wordpress but ... when i use the function it's showing me plain html and forget about all css! (in those section)

Comment: it should work ..... and check if you are getting additional html when calling this function.

Comment: Checked... no additional HTML..

Comment: can you also add the final html in your question? Which gets generated as a result of your php function call.

Comment: <a href="-----/category/test/" rel="category tag">Test</a>

Comment: Please add to the question.

Comment: It is wrapped inside `a` so it must be using CSS style of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="-----/category/test/" rel="category tag">Test</a>
```

That is the output of your PHP function according to your comment above. Your CSS works fine when you hard code the string `Test` but not when you get that output above. That only means one thing.

Your css styles are not for `a` tags under these classes `project-category text-faded` or `a` tag is style differently. So style your `a` tag appropriately for either of those and you're good.

Comment: Replacing the function with<a href="-----/category/test/" rel="category tag">Test</a> works with the same CSS ... is still a difference ?

Comment: Strange. Please edit your question and add the complete output that is generated after the PHP function call. Please include all of it including the div that is around it.

Comment: Thx for all support was totally my mistake i  accidentally deleted an </div> :'(